# Error while executing the Open MPI and Dask program

Tags: mpi, openmpi, dask-distributed

I am using Open MPI on Ubuntu(which is installed on a virtual machine). I am trying implement Mpi and Dask together.

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.array as da

def main():
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    rank = comm.Get_rank()

    # Start the Dask client
    client = Client()

    # Create a Dask array
    shape = (10000, 10000)
    chunks = (1000, 1000)
    x = da.ones(shape, chunks=chunks)

    # Perform some computation on the Dask array
    result = (x + x.T).sum()

    # Execute the computation and get the result
    total = client.compute(result)
    total = total.result()

    # Gather the final result
    total = comm.reduce(total, op=MPI.SUM, root=0)

    # Print the result on rank 0
    if rank == 0:
        print(f"Result: {total}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is my code. And when I execute it with "mpirun -np 3 python test.py" it is giving the following error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZL5B.jpg)

I also wrote a hello world program to test just mpi and it is working fine. The problem is when I try to combine dask and mpi.

any insights regarding this will be really helpfull.
Thank you

Another important thing is it is only happens when I try to execute using mpirun or mpiexec. when just run it directly using the run button in vs code it is giving the correct output.

Comment: does your hello world uses `mpi4py`? Assuming it does, are you saying `mpirun -np 3 python helloworld.py` works as expected (make sure to print the rank and confirms you indeed have ranks from `0` to `2`), but from the same terminal in the same directory, `mpirun -np 3 python test.py` fails with the error message you posted?

Comment: Could you also inline your code and comments directly in your post instead of using images?

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet yes, that is correct. It gives output from rank 0 to 2. it showing the error when I execute a code containing both dask and mpi4py libraries.